# Retrieve data from database and show it in textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am currently working on a web application in which I have to fetch data from database and show it in text boxes. I have these fields:

```
Name,Comp_Name,User_Name,Email_Id,Password,User_Image,Category,Status
```

and on top of it I have 1 text box where user can enter the id to see the data. For example if I write `1` in the textbox. Then the text boxes will show me the data of the record with `id=1` which is stored in database.

**ASPX Code:**

```
  <head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
   <link href="User.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="imgpreview.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function showimagepreview(input) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var filerdr = new FileReader();
   filerdr.onload = function(e) {
 $('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
 filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
   }
     </script>
 <style type="text/css">
    #Header
    {
        height: 65px;
    }
    .style1
    {
        height: 37px;
    }
    .style2
    {
        width: 217px;
        height: 37px;
    }
    .style3
    {
        height: 37px;
        width: 155px;
    }
    .style4
    {
        height: 129px;
        width: 155px;
    }
    .style5
    {
        width: 217px;
        height: 129px;
    }
    .style6
    {
        height: 129px;
    }
 </style>
 <script>
  window.onload=function()
{
   document.getElementById("button").style.display='none';

  }
    function showButton(){
    document.getElementById("button").style.display='block';
 }


    </script>

    </head>
     <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div id="Full">
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <div id="Main">
 <div id="MainHead">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="66px">
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&        nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="userText" value="Change the text"  runat="server"  />                  <asp:Button 
            ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  <br />
  <table style="height: 871px; width: 504px;">
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Name  :"></asp:Label>

  </td>
  <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
 ControlToValidate="txtName"
 Text="field required!"
  runat="server" />
 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="style3">

</td>
<td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
      <tr>
   <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="CompName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Comp Name  :"></asp:Label>

   </td>
  <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

   </td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="User Name  :"></asp:Label>

   </td>
  <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
  ControlToValidate="txtUser"
  Text="field required!"
  runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
 <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Password" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"      ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Email-ID  :"></asp:Label>

   </td>
   <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
  ControlToValidate="txtemail"
 Text="field required!"
  runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Password  :"></asp:Label>

  </td>
  <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtpass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style4">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Maroon" 
        Text="User Image  :"></asp:Label>

  </td>
  <td class="style5">

    <input type="file" name="filUpload" id="filUpload"     onchange="showimagepreview(this)"  runat="server"/>

  </td>
                    <td class="style6">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="122px">
                        <img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview"/>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Category  :"></asp:Label>

  </td>
  <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

   </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Status  :"></asp:Label>

    </td>
   <td class="style2">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtddl" runat="server" Height="28px" Width="151px" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Store Manager</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Pro Manager</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Engg</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>

    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"     ForeColor="Black" 
        Text="Category No  :"></asp:Label>

                    </td>
   <td class="style2">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcatno" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="151px">            </asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style3">

    &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="style2">

    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="style1" colspan="2">

                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&                   nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n      bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    &nbsp; 
    <asp:Button id="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click"          />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnupd" value="New Button" runat="server" onclick="return    btnupd_onclick()" />
                    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**C# Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("DataSource=localhost;database=mrp;userid=**;password=**;port=**");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
       {
            //This is my connection string i have assigned the database file address path
            string MyConnection2 =     "datasource=localhost;port=**;username=**;password=**;database=mrp";
            //This is my insert query in which i am taking input from the user through     windows forms
            string Query = "insert into user_tbl(Name,Comp_Name,User_Name,Email_Id,Password,User_Image,Category,Status) values('" +   this.txtName.Text + "','" + this.txtcomp.Text + "','" + this.txtuser.Text + "','" +    this.txtemail.Text + "','" + this.txtpass.Text + "','" + this.filUpload.Value + "','" +     this.txtcat.Text + "','" + this.txtddl.Text + "');";
            //This is  MySqlConnection here i have created the object and pass my      connection string.
             MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);

            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
            MyConn2.Open();
            MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();     // Here our query will be executed            and data saved into the database.
            MessageBox.Show("Save Data");
            while (MyReader2.Read())
            {

            }
            MyConn2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection("Data      Source=localhost;database=mrp;userid=**;password=**;port=**");
        var str = "select * from user_tbl,con1";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con1.Open();
        MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from user_tbl where Id=" + Id1, con1);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            txtName.Text = (myReader["Name"].ToString());
            txtemail.Text = (myReader["Email_Id"].ToString());
            txtddl.Text = (myReader["Status"].ToString());
            txtpass.Text = (myReader["Password"].ToString());
            txtcomp.Text = (myReader["Comp_Name"].ToString());
            txtuser.Text = (myReader["User_Name"].ToString());
            filUpload.Value = (myReader["User_Image"].ToString());

            //and whatever you have to retrieve
        }
       con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So- what have you tried ? What research have you done?

Comment: hello datrid.actually i want to insert anhd fetch the data on the same form.i am able to insert the data but i had seached alot on google to get an example of how to fetch the data through id and show it in textboxes but all the examples are for gridview and listview

Comment: It doesn't seems that you've already tried somthing and That sounds to be common task which you can find many samples, if you try searching it on web.

Comment: On which event do you want to show data on PageLoad or button click mention the place where you want to load data ?

Comment: @AlexJolig can you plz give me some links or code regarding this??

Comment: Ask from google, #1. how to read from database. #2. how to display values in textbox. #3. and hope you can combine both, if you cannot combine ask what you are unable to do.

Comment: @MairajAhmad i want to show data on page load..

Comment: On a side note, the way you are laying out your page is at least 10 years out of date. Google "table free page layout" and don't use `<br>` and `&nbps;` for spacing, learn CSS, in this instance `margin` and `padding`

Comment: Also use more meaningful class names for CSS. When you come back in a years time you will be scratching you head at what you were doing with `style1`

Comment: i will surely go through it.but right now i have to get out of this problem

Comment: what is `Id1` and where did you define it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con1.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = null;  
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("your query", con1);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    txtName.Text = (myReader["name"].ToString());
    txtEmail.Text = (myReader["email"].ToString());
    //and whatever you have to retrieve
}
con1.Close();
```

Comment: .the code is not showing any error but on runtime when i enter the id and click the button it does not fetch any data,it just reload the page

Comment: @MairajAhmad  i have posted my code with the html part ..u can take a look at it in the above code

Comment: @Shaharyar actully this code is working but when i enter any id in this i always get the last inserted record details